# How to make a customized symbol?

Tags: qgis

I am currently using QGIS version 2.16.1.

How can I make a customized symbol?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Thank you for taking the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in the manual (which is probably why you are getting down-votes and close-votes). If you still can't find it, try http://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/style_library.html?highlight=symbol

The short version is that you create an SVG (using editor of your choice, what is good depends on your experiences and is therefore inherently subjective, but inkscape is one option). Then add it to the symbol path (as described in the manual) using the big + symbol...